# A or The, what to use?

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article

> He treated me with the/a bitterness with which some old prisoners treat the new ones.

What to use in this sentence?

Comment: The use of article depends on the context, but there's no context provided. Btw, *bitterness* is uncountable, so it's not normally used with a definite article.

Comment: @user178049: The context given seems to me to be perfectly adequate to give a single definite answer, although I don't have time to do so right now.

Comment: but what is the answer?

Comment: @YuvrajKumar As I said, there's no enough context. Also, have you done any research? We want to see your effort.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to explain where this sentence came from and what you think about it, we should be able to reopen it. We can write better answers if we understand what you already know.

Answer (score 1):

Is the reader/listener expected to know which "bitterness" already?  If so, use *the*.  Otherwise use *a*/*an*.

Example reasons why the reader/listener would be expected to know which "bitterness" before that sentence:

- Prisoners and their mannerisms/habits/behavior, or prison in general, had been discussed before in previous sentences or conversation.
- Both the speaker/writer and reader/listener deal with (and know that each other deal with) prisoners on a regular basis - i.e. "the bitterness" is something that is shared knowledge or directly observable by both parties of the conversation.
- Sometimes a person wanting to assert authority, genuineness, or superiority will appear to "expect" someone else to know something that they really don't in order to intentionally leave them asking questions and feeling mentally defeated or lesser than the speaker/writer.